# Assign VPN users to Domain Network

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, firewall, windows

How can I assign VPN users (provided using NPS) to the Domain Network in firewall/network center settings?

Currently connection occurs only when I assign a particular rule to the Public network profile.

Answer (score 0):

At

```
GPEdit -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Network List Manager Policies
```

assign "RAS (Dial In) Interface" to a Private Network Profile what puts VPN clients there too.